# Using jQuery draggable() in a responsive environment…

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am working on a fairly typical image "reveal" effect using jQuery UI’s draggable() method; I’m having a lot of trouble making it work in a responsive environment:

http://codepen.io/ProfessorSamoff/pen/qEaNMM

As you’ll see, the reveal functionality works correctly at full size as well as when the browser window size is reduced. But the draggable handle doesn’t always snap to the proper position when the browser window is resized. (Although it does so when it’s clicked and dragged.)

Likewise, you’ll see that I have some commented code that checks against the browser window size:

```
if($(this).width() != width)
{
}
```

This works in order to get the draggable handle to the correct place when resizing the browser window, but it breaks the draggable functionality.

I have tried a few of the suggestions on Stack Overflow concerning draggable() and resizable(), but none of them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEmgBP

javascript now appears in this way:

```
var $reveal = $(".reveal");
$reveal.draggable({ 
    axis: "x",
    containment: "parent",
    iframeFix: true,
    refreshPositions: true,
    drag: function()
    {
      var position = $(this).position();
      var parentWidth = $(this).parent().width();
      var width = (position.left / parentWidth) * 100
      $(".featured").width(width + "%");
    }
  });

$(window).resize(function() {       
    $reveal.css('left', $(".featured").width()+'px')
});
```

It's not elegant but it seems to work.

basically I did 2 things:
1) I've setted $(".featured") width with %
2) on windows resize I change the position of the cursor with

```
$reveal.css('left', $(".featured").width()+'px')
```

note: point 2) is a workaround but I didn't find any way to move the cursor programatically. Maybe using a library to emulate the drag event (like https://github.com/mattheworiordan/jquery.simulate.drag-sortable.js/blob/master/README.md) you could find something better

Comment: Thank you! That definitely works! (Not perfect in all cases, but 99%.)